# How to send messages to android phone by using putty?

Tags: android, messaging

I want to send messages from android phone by using putty. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean, "using PuTTY"? Do you want to connect *to* an SSH server on the Android phone, and use a console command to send a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the telnet interface that is available for the emulator does not exist for hardware. You may be able to find a third-party SSH server or something, though that is not really in-scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: There's QuickSSHd (not $free, but cheap and reliable - I'm a happy user thereof), but even so: is it possible to invoke an Intent from the shell?

Comment: @Piskvor: I have no idea if the `am` command exists on hardware or is purely an emulator thing.

Comment: `# am start -a android.intent.action.MA
IN -n
ash: am: not found
` Looks like it's indeed an emulator thing only.